# Is there anything the priest does in Whiterun? (Skyrim)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there any special thing you can do with the priest blabbing about Talos all day or does he just stand there being obnoxious

Comment: I like to let him watch me enter his house so he'll come running to see why I'm in there, but getting in stealth before he gets in so I can backstab the *censored* out of him and shut him up for good.  But that's probably not the answer you're looking for....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are talking about Heimskr?

As with many other NPCs the Radiant system makes him a potential quest giver/quest target. Some of the potential quests in which he can be involved can be seen [here.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Radiant#Quest_NPCs)

[The Elder Scrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Heimskr) speaks of an additional two interactions with this NPC:

1. **After Battle for Whiterun**: His house will be destroyed during the battle; in the aftermath he will reside in a small tent next to the shrine of Talos or he can be jailed if the Legion wins the battle. Should the Stomcloaks take over Whiterun, Jarl Vignar Gray-Mane mentions building a temple of Talos in Whiterun, and making Heimskr the high priest.
2. **The Burglar Job**: His house may be the target for one of Vex's burglary jobs, in which the Dragonborn must steal a specific item. If his house has been destroyed, it becomes impossible to complete the burglary